Gradle Composite Build wait for includedBuild to finish
Gradle Version: 7.6.4
EDIT: After creating a small sample project that reproduces this behavior, it seems that the issue is with the AttributeCompatibilityRule. Because we consider "jar"=="edited-jar" it seems that Gradle goes directly to the jar task and its artifact and doesn't care about producing the edited-jar. Once the rule is removed, the editJar task properly enters the execution graph, however now it's impossible to compile because not all libraries generate edited-jar variants. Is this intended behavior? I'd expect that gradle would check all variants and give priority to the requested one and only if it doesn't exist fallback to a compatible one.
I have a gradle composite build using the includedBuild in the settings.gradle file.
#settings.gradle
rootProject.name = mainProj

includedBuild('library')

I only gradle build on the mainProj and it seems to properly build the library first then it goes on to build mainProj. This seems to work fine.
However, I have a scenario where where the resulting artifact of library must be edited in case of a release build (which I trigger using a property gradle -PreleaseBuild=true build). In library I have the following task:
#library

task editJar {
  dependsOn jar
  onlyIf {project.hasProperty('releaseBuild')}
  outputs.file file(jar.archiveFile)
  doLast {
    // open jar, do stuff, save it
  }
}
compileJava.finalizedBy editJar

In this case, when building mainProj it fails because it tries to build it while the editJar task is still ongoing (and thus the jar is not available as a dependency).
I followed gradle's variant aware dependency management and I have properly created a custom configuration
#library

configurations {
  editableJar {
    extendsFrom apiElements, runtimeElements
    canBeConsumed = true
    attributes {
    //...
    attribute(LibraryElements.LIBRARY_ELEMENTS_ATTRIBUTE, objects.named(LibraryElements, 'edited-jar'))
    }
  }
}

artifacts {
  editableJar(editJar.outputs.files.singleFile) {
    builtBy(editJar)
  }
}

and have properly set the attributeSchema with a rule:
#mainProj
abstract class EditedJarsRule implements AttributeCompatibilityRule<LibraryElements> {

    @Override
    void execute(CompatibilityCheckDetails<LibraryElements> details) {
        if (details.consumerValue.name == 'edited-jar' && details.producerValue.name == 'jar') {
            details.compatible()
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
  attributesSchema {
    attribute(LibraryElements.LIBRARY_ELEMENTS_ATTRIBUTE) {
      compatibilityRules.add(EditedJarsRule)
    }
  }
  implementation 'org.libs:library'
}

and have added attribute requirement to the configurations
# mainProj
  if(project.hasProperty('releaseBuild')) {
    compileClasspath {
      attributes {
        attribute(LibraryElements.LIBRARY_ELEMENTS_ATTRIBUTE, objects.named(LibraryElements, 'edited-jar'))
      }
    }
    runtimeClasspath {
      attributes {
        attribute(LibraryElements.LIBRARY_ELEMENTS_ATTRIBUTE, objects.named(LibraryElements, 'edited-jar'))
      }
    }
  }

In this case, it seems that my mainProj build does not wait until the library:editJar task is finished, even though the variant is properly requested (I have checked the dependency-insights).
I would expect this to be properly supported even in composite builds because I'm just relying on configurations and attributes, something that is properly resolved by gradle in the task graph, not to mention the task order works fine when not in release build (i.e. gradle supports ordering in includedBuilds).

I would agree that this can work (I recall that the documentation is a bit coy on using variant-aware matching on the outputs of included builds but I have had success with this approach). Your setup looks fine as far as it goes but you have not shown all relevant parts of it, including how the library is included is a dependency, and how a release build is selected.

Adding that info

@SimonJacobs is it possible that the issue is that my editJar is set with finalizedBy instead of a dependsOn which makes gradle not add it in the graph as a "dependent" task??

I don't think so. If mainProj requests the correct configuration, that should trigger editJar to be run to produce the artifact, and then editJar in turn depends on jar which triggers the whole regular Java compilation and build.

Indeed, I checked the builtBy command and it says that the provided tasks are treated the same way as dependsOn which should create a task dependency for anyone requesting the artifact with the editable-jar attribute.

There's a couple of things that don't look right.

You need to set the configuration attributes in two places:
(i) the outgoing configuration in the library project which holds the artifact, and
(ii) the incoming configuration in the main project which receives the dependencies.
You look to have done (i) correctly on editableJar. However for (ii) you have modified compileClasspath and runtimeClasspath, which are built from configurations that receive dependencies, but they do not accept dependencies directly (in Gradle terminology, isCanBeDeclared is false). The configuration you almost certainly need to amend is instead implementation (compileOnly and runtimeOnly are other credible options).

I see nowhere where you have actually added the library project as a dependency in the main project. You need to do something like:
// In the main build.gradle
dependencies {
    implementation 'libraryGroup:library:libraryVersion'
}

where you are using the group, name and version of the library project as set in that project's build. This is available via the included build dependency substitution rules.


Edited:
Thinking further, I doubt that editing the LibraryElements attribute of the implementation configuration is the way to go as this will affect any other dependencies that you are including in this configuration. Better to create a fresh configuration that implementation extends from and then you do not pollute existing implementation dependencies.

I indeed use implementation 'org.libs:library' to declare the dependency. Regarding the attributes, I was under the impression that since implementation extends runtimeClasspath would thus inherit the attributes. Regardless, I gave the attributes to implementation config but still get the same error.

The error being?

That the library:editJar task is seen to run in parallel with the mainProj:compileJava and because the editJar task is doing stuff with the dependency, mainProj:compileJava fails with weird file not found or EOF errors etc. since it expects to find files that are being deleted/recreated.

I would take it step by step to debug it. You need to make sure the correct JAR is being built by the editJar task. And you can make sure that same JAR is being added to the compileClasspath configuration later. Most of your code is written in a different fashion than I would write it so I can't be 100% sure it's ok. Eg you should only need to write artifacts { editableJar(editJar) }, and in your artifacts block editJar seems to have a lowercase 'J'. I've also added another point to the answer

After creating a small project to reproduce, it looks like the problem is the compatibility rule. I have edited my question at the top with new information.

I don't know what you're trying to do with the compatibility rule. You only need to set attributes on the configurations, like the Gradle example

The compatibility rule is needed because external dependencies for example are not variants with the edited-jar attribute. This means that I need to consider jar variants as compatible when a consumer requests edited-jar (e.g. if I'm including spring for example). However, it looks like this compatibility rule takes precedence and since Library generates both jar and edited-jar variants, the jar one takes precedence since it's generated first.

That's why I suggested setting up a new configuration in my edit in the answer above to keep it simple.
